# Creating a empty table along with partition and index is taking Forever in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

We are trying to Creating an empty table along with partition and index in oracle, But it is taking a very long time is there a way to speed up the process like using Parallel processing, etc?

NOTE: We are using the following version "Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production"

Comment: Check if there is no any process that locks objects. We had similar issue, but for truncate. It was abandoned OS process that had held the data file, but oracle didn't know about it

Comment: @astentx ok let me look into it

Comment: And a create table or index, is not done in parallel unless it is a create table as select, or indexing  a table that has data. when Oracle creates the entries in the dictionary, it does not do so in parallel, even if you use parallel i n the DDL.